# $COF(\lambda)$ is stationary in $k$, where $\lambda < k$ is regular.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I want to prove that:
if $\lambda < k$ is regular then $COF(\lambda) = \{\alpha < k | cof(\alpha) = \lambda \}$ is stationary in $k$.
I think I have to use that if $\alpha \neq \lambda$ is a cardinal in $COF(\lambda)$ then $\alpha$ is singular, so exist an increasing sequence $<k_i | i < cof(\alpha) = \lambda>$ such that $\alpha = sup_{i < \lambda} k_i$.
If there's a way to show that i can choose the $k_i$-s in a club $C$ for every club C of $k$ then the proof is done. How can I make it? Is the idea correct? Maybe something is missing because I don't see where I would use the regularity of $\lambda$. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Consider any club subset of $\kappa $. Check that it has order type $\kappa>\lambda $, and that its $\lambda $th element  (in its increasing enumeration) has cofinality $\lambda $.

Comment: The argument uses that $\kappa $ is regular (actually, that $\operatorname {cf}(\kappa)>\lambda$), to ensure that any club on $\kappa $ has a $\lambda $th member. That $\lambda $ is regular is used to ensure that this point has cofinality $\lambda $.

Comment: Assuming that any club subset $C$ of $k$ has order type $k$ then 
if $\beta_i$ is the enumerating sequence of $C$ I think that $f : \lambda \to \beta_{\lambda}$ defined by : for all $\alpha < \lambda$,  $f(\alpha) = \beta_{\alpha}$ is cofinal (i'm not sure if it's correct and i don't know how to prove it).  Anyway I don't understand why $ot(C) = k$.

Comment: $C $ is a subset of $\kappa $, so it cannot have larger order type. $\kappa $ is regular, so the enumerating sequence of $C $ cannot have length shorter than $\kappa $, or else $C $ would not be unbounded in $\kappa $.

Comment: Ok, that's clear! Thank you! What about $cof(\beta_\lambda)$? The function defined in my comment is cofinal but why there's no other cofinal function from an ordinal $\alpha < \lambda$ ? I thought that $\beta_\lambda \geq \lambda$ and  if there was a cofinal function $g : \alpha \to \beta_{\lambda}$ where $\alpha < \lambda$ I coud find a sequence (with set of indeces of cardinality less than $\lambda$) of elements of $ran(g)$ that reaches $\lambda$, but $\lambda$ is regular. Am i right?

Comment: Maybe, since there is the iso between $C$ and $k$ (has well ordered sets) the $\lambda_{th}$ element of $C$ must have the cofinality of the $\lambda_{th}$ element of $k$, that is $\lambda$. So $cof(\beta_{\lambda}) = cof(\lambda) = \lambda$. Better?

Comment: The sequence $\alpha\mapsto\beta_\alpha $, $\alpha <\lambda$, is cofinal in $\beta_\lambda $ (since $C $ is closed), it is strictly increasing, and has length $\lambda $, so $\operatorname{cf}(\beta_\lambda)=\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)=\lambda $, where the last equality is because $\lambda $ is regular.